# Bash Command as Bash Command Argument

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have a daemonised Docker container. I can execute multiple bash commands in one go as current user in that container like this:

```
docker exec -it <container_ID> /bin/bash -c "pwd; cd src; pwd"
```

I now need to do this through a bash script. The script is simple:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Here I do stuff to acquire the container_ID
docker exec -it <container_ID> -user $(id -u):$(id -g) $@
```

And then I pass arguments to the script, like this:

```
./run_in_container.sh /bin/bash -c "pwd; cd src; pwd"
```

Which does not work as expected, because the quotes are stripped, and what docker exec gets is `/bin/bash -c pwd; cd src; pwd`. So I try the following:

```
./run_in_container.sh /bin/bash -c '"pwd; cd src; pwd"'
```

And I get this error message:

```
cd: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
cd: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

What would be the correct way of doing this?

I doubt this is very important information in this case, but I am using Gnu bash 4.3.11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use quotes around `$@`:

```
docker exec -it <container_ID> -user $(id -u):$(id -g) "$@"
```

Comment: That indeed works! As soon as I store that in a variable though, like `COMMAND=$@`, then using "${COMMAND}" does not work any more. I know that is not the question I asked, but any idea why assigning it to a variable makes it fail?